# How can an Android application directly trigger an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke one AWS Lambda function from my Android application. If I understand correctly, I have to start with something like this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyId, secret);
AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
            .withRegion(regionName);
```

AWSLambda lambdaClient = builder.build();
and then the rest of the code with InvokeRequest etc.

Problem is in the above code, after it app crashes. I can't find the correct set of libs to make this work in Android. If I use

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.782'
```

then it compiles fine and executes up to the "builder.build()" and then crashes and if I use

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.16.12'
```

which is supposed to be used for Android (?) Then

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;
```

is red because there's no such thing in the lib.

I get that `AWSLambdaClient` is deprecated and AWSLambda should be used, then what about `AWSLambdaClientBuilder`? What should I use?

Basically, if everything above is wrong, how do I get to call AWS Lambda function (by the way, this is without using API Gateway) from an Android app? What libs (with versions) would work for it?

I tried to follow [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with the Mobile SDK for Android - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-android-example.html) tutorial, but they also have deprecated stuff, plus it wants to involve Cognito and I was under the impression that I could call a function directly with a key and secret of a user with specific policy.

Comment: It would be unwise to put AWS credentials inside your Android application. The app might be reverse-engineered and the credentials extracted. Also, it would be very difficult to change the credentials. The typical process would be for users to authenticate and then you can provide 'temporary credentials' to the application. If you want the app to call an API without requiring credentials then you could do it via API Gateway in front of the Lambda function, or by using a [Lambda function URL - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html).

Answer (score 1):

To build an Android app to invoke AWS Services, use the Brand new SDK - which is **AWS SDK for Kotlin**. The SDK for Kotlin uses suspend functions for all operations, which are meant to be called from a coroutine. DO not use Java V1 or even Java V2.

To invoke a Lambda function, you use this Kotlin code:

```
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.lambda.LambdaClient
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.lambda.model.LogType
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

// snippet-end:[lambda.kotlin.invoke.import]


/**
Before running this Kotlin code example, set up your development environment,
including your credentials.

For more information, see the following documentation topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
 */

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val usage = """
        Usage: <functionName> 

        Where:
        functionName - the name of the Lambda function to invoke (for example, myLambda). 
       """

    if (args.size != 1) {
        println(usage)
        exitProcess(1)
    }

    val functionName = args[0]
    invokeFunction(functionName)
}

// snippet-start:[lambda.kotlin.invoke.main]
suspend fun invokeFunction(functionNameVal: String) {

    val json = """{"inputValue":"1000"}"""
    val byteArray = json.trimIndent().encodeToByteArray()
    val request = InvokeRequest {
        functionName = functionNameVal
        logType = LogType.Tail
        payload = byteArray
    }

    LambdaClient { region = "us-west-2" }.use { awsLambda ->
        val res = awsLambda.invoke(request)
        println("${res.payload?.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)}")
        println("The log result is ${res.logResult}")
    }
}
```

See the DEV Guide.

[What is the AWS SDK for Kotlin?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

To learn how to build a Native Android app using this SDK, see this example:

[Creating a publish/subscription Android application that translates messages using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/subpub_app_android)

This example uses Android Studio Electric Eel and walks you through building a sample app that shows all Kotlin dependencies and invokes Amazon Simple Notification Service and Amazon Translate.

This app works and does not crash.

[image]

UPDATE

[Announcing general availability of the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-kotlin-ga/#:%7E:text=We%20are%20excited%20to%20announce,AWS%20service%20calls%20using%20coroutines.)